# Derivation of the entropy formula of Clausius

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

In my mathematical statistical physics class our professor derived the formula of Clausius d$S=\frac{\text{d}Q}{T}$. I have a problem with understanding one of the steps he is doing in his derivation. First we defined the temperature $T$ as as the expected kinetic energy, which can be also written as the expected momentum of the particle squared: $T=\mathbb{E}(E_{\text{kin}})=\mathbb{E}(k^2)$. Then he claims

\begin{align}
\text{d}S = S_2-S_1 = \ln\frac{|\Omega_2|}{|\Omega_1|}=\ln \frac{T_2^{3/2}}{T_1^{3/2}}= \ln\frac{(T+\text{d}Q)^{3/2}}{T^{3/2}}= \frac{3}{2}\ln\frac{T+\text{d}Q}{T}= \frac{3}{2}\ln\left(1+\frac{\text{d}Q}{T}\right)= \frac{3}{2}\frac{\text{d}Q}{T}
\end{align}
since $\text{d}Q$ is very small. With $|\Omega|$ he denotes (if I understand it right) the number of given microstates of the system.

The step which I absolutely do not understand is the third equality: $\ln\frac{|\Omega_2|}{|\Omega_1|}=\ln \frac{T_2^{3/2}}{T_1^{3/2}}$. What does the $|\Omega|$ have to do with $T^{3/2}$ and how do one see this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The Sackur -Tetrode expression for entropy has been used. I find it much more difficult to justify the sum of $T$ and $dQ$. Moreover, at the end of the day, there is a factor $3/2$ wrong. Maybe you should check your notes.

Comment: @GiorgioP thats interesting, i have never heard of Sackur-Tetrode. I checked the slides of my professor again and he definitely has this factor 3/2 in his calculation... but i mean he maybe just did a mistake somewhere..

Comment: The main problem is that the final formula contains the wrong factor. You may find about Sackur-Tetrode on Wikipedia. A final comment is that in any case the whole calculation cannot be considered as a derivation of the Clausius' formula. It would be limited to the case of an ideal gas, while Clausis' formula is valid for every thermodynamic system.